# Payment Splitter in Solana

Tags: solana-program

EVM has an official [payment splitter](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.7/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol) smart contract. What about a Solana program? Is there is something official?

Answer (score 3):

Metaplex has a fanout wallet that does exactly this. Number of shares is customizable and can be split between any number of members.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/hydra

Cardinal also made a handy UI for it.

https://hydra.cardinal.so/

The only downside is the funds need to be disbursed manually since Solana doesn't have automatic crank capabilities. But disbursement is permissionless so it can be done by any wallet.